# «Захолустье»: этимология

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Захолустным называется маленький заштатный городишко — далеко от центра, глухая провинция. А что это слово означает? Какова этимология?
"За-холустье" значит "за — чем"?

Answer (score 2):

Это исконное слово. Скорее всего, видоизменение — под влиянием слов типа замостье и т. д. — захолужье (ср. также диал. захалузье), суф. производного на базе за халугой «за изгородью» (не в селе, а за околицей).

Comment: Поддерживаю, хотя Фасмер это считает сомнительным. Халуга- изгородь из хлуди. Хлудь-жердь.Ср.-холудина(длинный, как жердь) образовалось от слова "хлудь"-"жердь"."О" появилось , как в "закорючке" от "крюк".